# Strategy for multi-repository dependencies

Tags: .net-core, nuget

In our codebase, different levels of abstraction are defined in separate projects, where each are built as nuget packages that can be referenced by other projects.
Most of the time each project is in its own repository. Packages are named according to the branch they are created on.
We have major headaches every time we update an upstream package - we have to ensure that all of the repositories that use a package are updated and rebuilt, and then cascade the updated versions of those projects into their dependents, etc.

Of course when branches are merged and they generate the "release" packages we have to do it all over again as well.

Two solutions are obvious: move everything into the same repository and just use project references everywhere, and write a script that will manipulate project files to point at particular versions of packages.
Debugging is of course difficult as we can't commit project references since they are all in different repositories so could be anywhere relative to a given project.

Are there any other ideas apart from the above we could look at? E.g. a way to use git to reference other repos, so we can reliably use project references but keep the separate repos?
Or some kind of central library that everything looks at for its reference versions?
Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules this might work for you